# Parse.com Pointer query return empty object

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to get a user information from a table pointer but sound like it return empty object with just a user id

```
return new Parse.Query('grupoUser').include('user').equalTo("id_user", user).find().then(function ($zones)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < $zones.length; i++)
    {
        var zone = $zones[i];
        user = zone.get("id_user").getUsername();//return undefined
        user = zone.get("id_user"); // return a empty object with user id

    }
    return results || null;

}, function(response)
{
    return {};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code supplied, the property name is `id_user` not `user`, so your first line should look like this:

```
return new Parse.Query('grupoUser')
    .include('id_user')
    .equalTo('id_user', user)
    .find()
    .then(function ($zones)
{
  // etc...
```

Comment: You save my day! 
i Thought you need to include the table, not the field!
tks a bunch